# I lost all of my unlocks and challenges in Aliens: Colonial Marines; is it possible to get them back?

Tags: xbox-360, aliens-colonial-marines

Yesterday I bought the Sawed-Off Double-Barrel Shotgun for Aliens: Colonial Marines on XBOX 360; I get on the game, and all of my stuff has been reset: my skins, my challenges, my campaign progress, my weapons, my perks; everything. It left me so upset, and I want to know if there is any way to get my stuff back.

Comment: "Some customers are having issues with loss of save data for this title on Xbox 360.  To prevent this from occurring in the future, please be sure to sign in to your XBL profile before starting the game or downloading any patches.  **While it doesn’t appear possible to recover your lost data**, these steps should prevent it from happening again.  We are following this issue very closely and Gearbox has been and continues to make efforts to improve the stability of save data for this title." https://help.sega.com/entries/23337948-Aliens-Colonial-Marines-Known-Issues-Workarounds

Comment: That should be the answer.